# Segmentation fault while starting Jupyter

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, jupyter, ipython, jupyter-lab

I'm using Linux Mint and while starting jupyter-lab using `jupyter-lab` command an error appears:

```
[C 2023-03-27 17:01:18.983 ServerApp] 
    
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/glebi/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-11376-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=e09a619571243de83c52db5adeda6ef305d2ece10f0b3bac
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=e09a619571243de83c52db5adeda6ef305d2ece10f0b3bac
[I 2023-03-27 17:01:20.144 LabApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 2f0803e3dfa84a03a7aa280c48717b4d
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have a kernel (`jupyter kernelspec list`):

```
Available kernels:
  python3    /home/glebi/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

`jupyter-notebook` works well until I don't try to open my past Notebooks. Then segfault appears again.

I've spent the whole day trying to reinstall jupyter, ipython and pyzmq with pip (I also reinstalled it few times), but it didn't work. I will be glad of any help.

#### UPD:

As suggested by **Beatdown**, I looked at the logs and the `/var/log/kern.log` contains the following information:

```
Mar 27 17:27:07 magicbook kernel: [  306.552478] jupyter-lab[3841]: segfault at 248d ip 00007f56e4b6dbba sp 00007ffccb4e1120 error 4 in _json.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so[7f56e4b6c000+7000]
Mar 27 17:27:07 magicbook kernel: [  306.552492] Code: 00 0f b7 4c 5d 00 44 8d 41 d0 66 41 83 f8 09 0f 87 1f f9 ff ff 48 8d 58 02 48 39 de 7c 17 0f b7 44 5d 00 83 e8 30 66 83 f8 09 <22> 86 f0 21 00 00 e9 ff f8 ff ff e9 38 18 00 00 e9 33 18 00 00 4c
```

Comment: Few suggestions 1) make sure your system is updated 2) run jypyter lab in a virtual environment 2) check /var/log for any error logs 3) try a different Linux distribution 4) try a different version of Python